# App Inventor 2 Pizza Party query not working

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I completed the App Inventor 2 Pizza Party sample without any problems and now I wanted to try to query the fusion table by searching for specific items. In this case after I press the Submit button,  I want to see in the `webviewer`, all items in the Pizza column that have Cheese.

When  I run this app from my phone, I get everything in the table, not just the rows with Cheese. I know I'm doing something wrong but after quite a bit of time looking for examples and trying things myself, I'm stuck. Appreciate any help or ideas. Thank you.

[image]

I'll post this also in the [MIT App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/1X7f1LOfZ-I/0mK5unon_GcJ). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before asking here, it's a good idea to [do the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to learn, [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... but probably [my answer in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/1X7f1LOfZ-I/HfVj2ULXNo4J) is already what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, you have been very helpful, I just got your latest example to work. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I won't be using this forum any longer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to display the result in the webviewer directly, you have to modify the URL of the webviewer accordingly, see screenshot

[image]

[example URL](https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=TABLE&q=select%20*%20from%201Ty90w_LWJEgZHNwEWgoebigLDEXPYLAgJHVHSFkk%20WHERE%20Pizza%20%3D%27Cheese%27&containerId=googft-gviz-canvas)